# What is the difference between static func and class func in Swift?

Tags: class, static, swift

I can see these definitions in the Swift library:

```
extension Bool : BooleanLiteralConvertible {
    static func convertFromBooleanLiteral(value: Bool) -> Bool
}

protocol BooleanLiteralConvertible {
    typealias BooleanLiteralType
    class func convertFromBooleanLiteral(value: BooleanLiteralType) -> Self
}
```

What's the difference between a member function defined as `static func` and another one defined as `class func`? Is it simply that `static` is for static functions of structs and enums, and `class` for classes and protocols? Are there any other differences that one should know about? What is the rationale for having this distinction in the syntax itself?

Comment: There is no difference really. They couldn't use class func in a struct I guess, hence static func. struct func would have been a good candidate. This is a bit edgy if you ask me but well, those are the words.

Comment: Bonus question, then: can a struct conform to a protocol that defines a `class func`? With the information we have now, this distinction seems rather useless, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, you can. Strange isn't it?

Comment: the overwhelming difference is you can override `class func`s

Comment: To be considered: `error: class methods are only allowed within classes; use 'static' to declare a static method`

Answer (score 295, accepted):

> Is it simply that static is for static functions of structs and enums, and class for classes and protocols?

That's the main difference. Some other differences are that class functions are dynamically dispatched and can be overridden by subclasses.

Protocols use the class keyword, but it doesn't exclude structs from implementing the protocol, they just use static instead. Class was chosen for protocols so there wouldn't have to be a third keyword to represent static or class.

From Chris Lattner on this topic:

> We considered unifying the syntax (e.g. using "type" as the keyword), but that doesn't actually simply things.  The keywords "class" and "static" are good for familiarity and are quite descriptive (once you understand how + methods work), and open the door for potentially adding truly static methods to classes.  The primary weirdness of this model is that protocols have to pick a keyword (and we chose "class"), but on balance it is the right tradeoff.

And here's a snippet that shows some of the override behavior of class functions:

```
class MyClass {
    class func myFunc() {
        println("myClass")
    }
}

class MyOtherClass: MyClass {
    override class func myFunc() {
        println("myOtherClass")
    }
}

var x: MyClass = MyOtherClass()
x.dynamicType.myFunc() //myOtherClass
x = MyClass()
x.dynamicType.myFunc() //myClass
```

Comment: Aha, very important point that class functions are dynamically dispatched! But could you provide such an example? You'd have to write the class name somewhere, right? So why not statically choose the implementation of that class?

Comment: Another complementary question: where did you get the quote from?

Comment: my understanding is that class functions work pretty much the same as objc + methods under the hood

Comment: Can I provide a simpler answer link here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636633/static-vs-class-functions-variables-in-swift-classes

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet In the example above...if you use `static func myFunc()` instead of `class func myFunc` you will get the following error l: **cannot override static method**. Why? Because it's as if its been marked with `final`. For more information. See nextD's answer below. Also `x.dynamicType` has now been replaced with `type(of:x)`

Comment: @connor your link is now dead :(

Comment: What does `dynamically dispatched` mean ?

Answer (score 391):

To be clearer, I make an example here,

```
class ClassA {
    class func func1() -> String {
        return "func1"
    }
    
    static func func2() -> String {
        return "func2"
    }
}

/* same as above
    final class func func2() -> String {
        return "func2"
    }
*/
```

`static func` is same as `final class func`

Because it is `final`, we can not override it in subclass as below:

```
class ClassB: ClassA {
    override class func func1() -> String {
        return "func1 in ClassB"
    }
    
    // ERROR: Class method overrides a 'final` class method
    override static func func2() -> String {
        return "func2 in ClassB"
    }
}
```

Comment: you champ , great answer ..i was seeking this diffrence .. Jake!!

Comment: Perfect. Impressive.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Neat and Clean!

Comment: Best explanation! This leaded me to another doubt. Is there any explicit reason to use a 'class func'? I mean if you just use 'func' it also can be overridden the same way, so what's the difference?

Comment: @MarcosReboucas if I understand your question correctly, `class func` is different from normal `func` although both can be overridden.  But `func` is for an instance/object and `class func` can be accessed through the class like `ClassA.classFunc()`

Answer (score 89):

I did some experiments in playground and got some conclusions.

**TL;DR**
[image]

As you can see, in the case of `class`, the use of `class func` or `static func` is just a question of habit.

**Playground example with explanation:**

```
class Dog {
    final func identity() -> String {
        return "Once a woofer, forever a woofer!"
    }

    class func talk() -> String {
        return "Woof woof!"
    }

    static func eat() -> String {
        return "Miam miam"
    }

    func sleep() -> String {
        return "Zzz"
    }
}

class Bulldog: Dog {
    // Can not override a final function
//    override final func identity() -> String {
//        return "I'm once a dog but now I'm a cat"
//    }

    // Can not override a "class func", but redeclare is ok
    func talk() -> String {
        return "I'm a bulldog, and I don't woof."
    }

    // Same as "class func"
    func eat() -> String {
        return "I'm a bulldog, and I don't eat."
    }

    // Normal function can be overridden
    override func sleep() -> String {
        return "I'm a bulldog, and I don't sleep."
    }
}

let dog = Dog()
let bullDog = Bulldog()

// FINAL FUNC
//print(Dog.identity()) // compile error
print(dog.identity()) // print "Once a woofer, forever a woofer!"
//print(Bulldog.identity()) // compile error
print(bullDog.identity()) // print "Once a woofer, forever a woofer!"

// => "final func" is just a "normal" one but prevented to be overridden nor redeclared by subclasses.


// CLASS FUNC
print(Dog.talk()) // print "Woof woof!", called directly from class
//print(dog.talk()) // compile error cause "class func" is meant to be called directly from class, not an instance.
print(Bulldog.talk()) // print "Woof woof!" cause it's called from Bulldog class, not bullDog instance.
print(bullDog.talk()) // print "I'm a bulldog, and I don't woof." cause talk() is redeclared and it's called from bullDig instance

// => "class func" is like a "static" one, must be called directly from class or subclassed, can be redeclared but NOT meant to be overridden.

// STATIC FUNC
print(Dog.eat()) // print "Miam miam"
//print(dog.eat()) // compile error cause "static func" is type method
print(Bulldog.eat()) // print "Miam miam"
print(bullDog.eat()) // print "I'm a bulldog, and I don't eat."

// NORMAL FUNC
//print(Dog.sleep()) // compile error
print(dog.sleep()) // print "Zzz"
//print(Bulldog.sleep()) // compile error
print(bullDog.sleep()) // print "I'm a bulldog, and I don't sleep."
```

Comment: Your examples do not cover the case mentioned as main difference in another answer: dynamic dispatch of `class` functions vs. static binding of `static` ones.

Comment: Great explanation for understanding functions.

Comment: Isn't `class func` overridable?

Comment: If you try to override a static method you WILL GET AN ERROR. However you *can* override a class method. See the accepted answer

Comment: `class func` is overridable. I woulda voted this up otherwise; love the research and example!

Comment: Gotta love the TL;DR sometimes. I've been writing classes for network calls and been wondering if sometimes I should use class func over the normal func.

Comment: I like the TL;DR approach too but class functions are overridable and need the keyword `override`

Comment: Please edit this answer, because it contains incorrect information (class func is overridable)

Answer (score 54):

> To declare a type variable property, mark the declaration with the `static` declaration modifier. Classes may mark type computed properties with the `class` declaration modifier instead to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation. Type properties are discussed in Type Properties.
>
> > *NOTE*
> > In a class declaration, the keyword `static` has the same effect as marking the declaration with both the `class` and `final` declaration modifiers.

Source: [The Swift Programming Language - Type Variable Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID483)

Comment: The question is asking about 'static func' and 'class func'. It is NOT asking about Type Properties. So this doesn't answer the question - though it is important to understand the context of these keywords in regards to properties as well.

Comment: This answer is simply on the wrong question, perhaps it was posted here accidentally?

Answer (score 28):

Both the **static** and **class** keywords allow us to attach methods to a class rather than to instances of a class. For example, you might create a Student class with properties such as name and age, then create a static method numberOfStudents that is owned by the Student class itself rather than individual instances.

Where **static** and **class** differ is how they support inheritance. When you make a static method it becomes owned by the class and can't be changed by subclasses, whereas when you use class it may be overridden if needed.

Here is an Example code:

```
class Vehicle {
    static func getCurrentSpeed() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
    
    class func getCurrentNumberOfPassengers() -> Int {
        return 0
    } 
}

class Bicycle: Vehicle {
    //This is not allowed
    //Compiler error: "Cannot override static method"
    //static override func getCurrentSpeed() -> Int {
        //return 15
    //}
    
    class override func getCurrentNumberOfPassengers() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but not sure about the added value with respect to the already proposed and highly voted answers…

Answer (score 24):

This example will clear every aspect!

```
import UIKit

class Parent {
    final func finalFunc() -> String { // Final Function, cannot be redeclared.
        return "Parent Final Function."
    }

    static func staticFunc() -> String { // Static Function, can be redeclared.
        return "Parent Static Function."
    }

    func staticFunc() -> String { // Above function redeclared as Normal function.
        return "Parent Static Function, redeclared with same name but as non-static(normal) function."
    }

    class func classFunc() -> String { // Class Function, can be redeclared.
        return "Parent Class Function."
    }

    func classFunc() -> String { // Above function redeclared as Normal function.
        return "Parent Class Function, redeclared with same name but as non-class(normal) function."
    }

    func normalFunc() -> String { // Normal function, obviously cannot be redeclared.
        return "Parent Normal Function."
    }
}

class Child:Parent {

    // Final functions cannot be overridden.

    override func staticFunc() -> String { // This override form is of the redeclared version i.e: "func staticFunc()" so just like any other function of normal type, it can be overridden.
        return "Child Static Function redeclared and overridden, can simply be called Child Normal Function."
    }

    override class func classFunc() -> String { // Class function, can be overidden.
        return "Child Class Function."
    }

    override func classFunc() -> String { // This override form is of the redeclared version i.e: "func classFunc()" so just like any other function of normal type, it can be overridden.
        return "Child Class Function, redeclared and overridden, can simply be called Child Normal Function."
    }

    override func normalFunc() -> String { // Normal function, can be overridden.
        return "Child Normal Function."
    }
}

let parent = Parent()
let child = Child()

// Final
print("1. " + parent.finalFunc())   // 1. Can be called by object.
print("2. " + child.finalFunc())    // 2. Can be called by object, parent(final) function will be called.
// Parent.finalFunc()               // Cannot be called by class name directly.
// Child.finalFunc()                // Cannot be called by class name directly.

// Static
print("3. " + parent.staticFunc())  // 3. Cannot be called by object, this is redeclared version (i.e: a normal function).
print("4. " + child.staticFunc())   // 4. Cannot be called by object, this is override form redeclared version (normal function).
print("5. " + Parent.staticFunc())  // 5. Can be called by class name directly.
print("6. " + Child.staticFunc())   // 6. Can be called by class name direcly, parent(static) function will be called.

// Class
print("7. " + parent.classFunc())   // 7. Cannot be called by object, this is redeclared version (i.e: a normal function).
print("8. " + child.classFunc())    // 8. Cannot be called by object, this is override form redeclared version (normal function).
print("9. " + Parent.classFunc())   // 9. Can be called by class name directly.
print("10. " + Child.classFunc())   // 10. Can be called by class name direcly, child(class) function will be called.

// Normal
print("11. " + parent.normalFunc())  // 11. Can be called by object.
print("12. " + child.normalFunc())   // 12. Can be called by object, child(normal) function will be called.
// Parent.normalFunc()               // Cannot be called by class name directly.
// Child.normalFunc()                // Cannot be called by class name directly.

/*
 Notes:
 ___________________________________________________________________________
 |Types------Redeclare------Override------Call by object------Call by Class|
 |Final----------0--------------0---------------1------------------0-------|
 |Static---------1--------------0---------------0------------------1-------|
 |Class----------1--------------1---------------0------------------1-------|
 |Normal---------0--------------1---------------1------------------0-------|
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Final vs Normal function: Both are same but normal methods can be overridden.
 Static vs Class function: Both are same but class methods can be overridden.
 */
```

Output:
[image: Output all types of function]

Answer (score 15):

According to the Swift 2.2 Book published by apple:

“You indicate type methods by writing the `static` keyword before the method’s func keyword. Classes may also use the `class` keyword **to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation of that method**.”

Answer (score 10):

From Swift2.0, Apple says:

"Always prefix type property requirements with the static keyword when you define them in a protocol. This rule pertains even though type property requirements can be prefixed with the class or static keyword when implemented by a class:"

Answer (score -7):

This is called type methods, and are called with dot syntax, like instance methods. However, you call type methods on the type, not on an instance of that type. Here’s how you call a type method on a class called SomeClass:

Comment: class SomeClass {
    class func someTypeMethod() {
        // type method implementation goes here
    }
}
SomeClass.someTypeMethod()

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. He asked the difference between `static` and `class` keywords.