# Difference between struct static func vs class static func in swift?

Tags: swift, struct

I am not able to find any difference between `class static function` to `struct static function`. As I know class static function can not be inherited and struct does not have an option for inheritance.

> Please do not get confused by static func and class func in class.

```
class a {
    static func myMethod1() {
    }
}
```

vs

```
struct a {
    static func myMethod1() {
    }
}
```

Comment: They are the same except with `static` then you cant override it, thats why it's used for struct, since struct also cant be subclassed

Comment: They are the same. Both are statically dispatched (compile-time) methods on a type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is kind of a stretch, but due to the reference vs value semantics of `class` and `struct` types, respectively, there is subtle difference in in the realization of a case where you want to make use of a type method (`static`) to mutate a private property of the type, given an instance of the type has been supplied. Again, kind of a stretch, as this focuses on differences in implementation details, and not on a concrete difference between the two.

In the `class` case, an immutable reference can be supplied to the `static` method, which in turn can be used to mutate a private instance member of the type. In the case of the `struct`, the instance of the type naturally needs to be supplied as an `inout` parameter, as changing the value of an instance member of a value type also means changing the value of the instance itself.

```
class A {
    private(set) var i: Int = 0
    static func foo(_ bar: A) { 
        bar.i = 42
    }
}

struct B {
    private(set) var i: Int = 0
    static func foo(_ bar: inout B) { 
        bar.i = 42  
    }
}

let a = A()
var b = B()

A.foo(a)
print(a.i) // 42
B.foo(&b)
print(b.i) // 42
```

Comment: Although of course `A`'s `static func foo(_ bar: A)` is basically (ignoring the ability to access the metatype value that it's called on) an equivalent of `final func foo()` and `B`'s `static func foo(_ bar: inout B)` is basically an equivalent of `mutating func foo()` :) The only other difference I can think of is that by making them static and having an explicit parameter for the instance (rather than relying on the implicit `self` parameter), you gain the ability to overload them with different parameter types.

Comment: @Hamish yes, truly a stretch (and not entirely associated with `static`, but rather the inherent difference of value vs. reference types). Good point about the overloading possibility when being explicit!

Answer (score -1):

These link may help you to understand the functions. As [@mipadi says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29636742/2976878) (emphasis mine):

> `static` and `class` both associate a method with a class, rather than an
>   instance of a class. **The difference is that subclasses can override
>   `class` methods; they cannot override `static` methods.**
>
> `class` properties will theoretically function in the same way
>   (subclasses can override them), but they're not possible in Swift yet.

[What is the difference between static func and class func in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156377/what-is-the-difference-between-static-func-and-class-func-in-swift)

[Static vs class functions/variables in Swift classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636633/static-vs-class-functions-variables-in-swift-classes)

Comment: That's i know and you might have missed my question, it's about struct static func vs class static func, not about  static func and class func.

Comment: Mark question as duplicate if you think it is duplicate

Comment: Please don't just quote another answer without adding any content of your own. Quoting is fine (as long as you [give proper attribution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)), but you should use it to support *your own* ideas. If you feel a question is a duplicate, then please flag it as such (as it happens, it is not a duplicate – the answer you're quoting is talking about `class` methods vs. `static` methods, which the question is not about).

Answer (score -1):

**The difference is that subclasses can override class methods but cannot override static methods.**

Here is the simple example that is tested in the Playground

```
class A{
    class func classFunction(){
    }
    static func staticFunction(){
    }
}

class B: A {
    // override successfully
    override class func classFunction(){
    }

    //Compile Error. Cannot override static method
    override static func staticFunction(){
    }
}
```