# What is difference between static and class keyword in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, class, static

I am looking for the difference between static and class keyword in swift. Where do i need to use static vs class.

For e.g;

```
class MyClass {

    static func firstMethod() {}

    class func secondMethod() {}
}

 func doSomething() {
     myClass.firstMethod()
     myClass.secondMethod()
 }
```

So we can use like this;

> MyClass.secondMethod()
>
> MyClass.firstMethod()

So where should i use static or class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between static func and class func in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156377/what-is-the-difference-between-static-func-and-class-func-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

In general its enough to use `static` keyword, but Apple provide description that if you use struct - use static , if class - use class

`static` is same as `class final`

But i recommend to read article below, i hope everything will become cleaner after reading 
https://borgs.cybrilla.com/tils/global-vs-static-function-swift/