CoreData: keypath not found in entity Parent with userInfo of (null)
I have a CoreData model that defines a common Parent Entity for a few entities. I want to make a simple predicate but I keep getting crashes with the error that the keypath I'm searching with is not found on the parent entity, even though I declare the Predicate for the child entity.
Code:
@objc(ChildEntity)
public class ChildEntity: ParentEntity {

    public static func childEntityPredicate() -> NSPredicate {
        // Option 1
        NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(ChildEntity.propertyToQuery), true as NSNumber)
        // Option 2
        NSPredicate(format: "propertyToQuery == true")
    }
}

Neither options work, they both have the same output.
Error I'm getting with CoreData logging enabled:
error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x303d9d6c0> , keypath propertyToQuery not found in entity ParentEntity with userInfo of (null)

I don't think the syntax of the predicate is the culprit here (option 2 would have worked), but I don't know how to "force" CoreData to understand the predicate is done on the child entity, not the parent one.
Any thoughts?

How do you call that method? Is that method only on ChildEntity and not ParentEntity? If not, you might want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156377/what-is-the-difference-between-static-func-and-class-func-in-swift

The method is only on ChildEntity. The link provided is very useful, thank you!
I use domain models in the app and mirror them for the persistence layer (to isolate persistence in its own module) and for that particular call, I was actually using the model, not the NSManagedObject subclass. The error was there, but your comment made me look for that, so thank you!
