Is it possible to override/overload the static function?
Let's say this is the old view hierarchy:
UITabBarController
      |--------- NavigationController
                             |------- ViewController A
      |--------- NavigationController
                             |------- ViewController B
      ...

From the old code base, I had a static function that found the topmost controller on the screen. It was written within a separate module called HelperModule, something like:
public extension UIViewController {
    static func findBestVC(from viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
        if let presentedVC = viewController.presentedViewController {
            return findBestVC(from: presentedVC)
        } else if let splitVC = viewController as? UISplitViewController {
            if let lastVC = splitVC.viewControllers.last {
                return findBestVC(from: lastVC)
            }
        } else if let navVC = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            if let topVC = navVC.topViewController {
                return findBestVC(from: topVC)
            }
        } else if let tabVC = viewController as? UITabBarController {
            if let topVC = tabVC.moreNavigationController.topViewController, topVC.view.window != nil {
                return findBestVC(from: topVC)
            }
            else if let selectedVC = tabVC.selectedViewController {
                return findBestVC(from: selectedVC)
            }
        }
        return viewController
    }
}

So far so good, it worked previously and now. However, I adjusted the view hierarchy to:
UIViewController (Main)
        |
UIPageViewController (Main's child)
        |---------- UINavigationController
                                   |------ ViewController A
        |---------- UINavigationController
                                   |------ ViewController B
        ...

As a result, the static function above did not return the expected ViewController. It always returned MainController.
Question: is it possible to override/overload the static function from the module without affecting the legacy code base? Because it is used a lot in the current project, even within other modules.
Any suggestions/solutions would be appreciated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156377/what-is-the-difference-between-static-func-and-class-func-in-swift ?

@Larme, Thanks for sharing the link. I already knew how to override a class function. However, this circumstance is a bit different. I don't know how to: somehow replace findBestVC, which is in a separate module, with a function from the host app that depends on this module, without affecting the static function itself, because it's legacy code, and it's impacting too much.
